# Define Base URL Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON containing a database of movie information images "moviedb.json"

Example:

```
        "original_title": "Fury",
        "original_language": "en",
        "title": "Fury",
        "backdrop_path": "\/pKawqrtCBMmxarft7o1LbEynys7.jpg",
        "popularity": 11.717304,
        "vote_count": 2435,
        "video": false,
        "vote_average": 7.43
```

The image base URL is https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original how do I define and access it?

Comment: First you need to parse, something like `var obj = JSON.parse(moviedb)` then you can do `obj.URL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original"`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the .json file

```
var moviedbRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
moviedbRequest.addEventListener("load", parseMovies);
moviedbRequest.open("GET", "moviedb.json");
moviedbRequest.send();
```

You need to parse the JSON as an object, then get the backdrop_path from that object and append it to the base url

```
function parseMovies() {
    var data = JSON.parse(moviedbRequest.responseText);
    var url = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original' + data.backdrop_path;
}
```

You the url of the image will then be stored in the variable called `url`

Comment: Email me at xmlhttprequest@forward.cat